# Group GGPlot Colour Based on Row Number

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a plot that has 16 Observations on 5 columns. One of the columns is called "Name". Within the column name, I have car1-6 , truck1-5, and train 1-5 which makes up my 16 observations. I have:

```
ggplot(dftest, aes(x = Names, y= AVGMostLikely, ymin= BestCaseHi, ymax=WorstCaseLow)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_errorbar() + 
    ggtitle("Bar chart with Error Bars")
```

I want to have the fill/color of the bars to be based on the name where car1-6 will be one color, truck1-5 another, and train1-5 are a third color. Is this possible within ggplot?

Thanks for any help

Comment: In your `aes` function have you tried `fill = Names` ?

Comment: @DataJack That generates a new color for ever name (so 16 colors). I would like to only have a color for: car,truck,train (so 3 colors total).

Comment: You can do this, but you'll probably need to reshape your data first.

Comment: @JakeKaupp how would I reshape the data? The rows are in order (car1,car2,....,truck1,truck2,....,train1,....,train5)

Comment: There are many posts on SO about reshaping your data for use in `ggplot2`. Search away.

Comment: Do I have to reshape the data in order to have a grouping of rows to make them the same color within ggplot? A solution would be if "fill" could support subgroups.

Comment: Make a new variable the involves the "type" of vehicle for mapping to `fill`.  If I was doing this I'd probably pull out the words (but not the numbers) from the levels of your current "Name" variable to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to remove the last character in Your column `Names` (which is the number):

```
char_array = c("car1","car2","truck1","truck5")
data = data.frame("names"=char_array)
data$names = as.character(data$names)
data$groups = substr(data$names,1,nchar(data$names)-1)
```

Than You have a new column named `groups` which You can use as a `fill` argument in `ggplot`.